# Variables from custom subclass aren't saved/won't load from Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, subclass

I am making a drawing application that allows users to save and reopen drawings, hence why I need to use CoreData. One of the features is the ability to change the path colour. I need to store a colour in each UIBezierPath so it strokes it the right colour when it gets drawn. Hence I subclassed UIBezierPath:

```
class colorPath: UIBezierPath {

 var pathStrokeColor: UIColor?

}
```

I then draw the paths like this in the draw(_ rect:) function:

```
        for path in paths{
        path.pathStrokeColor?.setStroke()
        path.stroke()           
    }
```

This works fine until I close the application and reopen it. pathStrokeColor just has a nil value, and draws in the default colour -- Black.

The array of the path arrays are saved in Core Data entity JFile like this. "thearray" is of type transformable, so I convert the colorPath into NSObject:

```
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    let afile = JFile(context: context) 
    afile.thearray = arrayOfPages as NSObject

    (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()
```

The array of the path arrays are retrieved like this. I have to convert the NSObject array back into colorPath:

```
   let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
                        let jfiles = try context.fetch(JFile.fetchRequest())
                        let filez = files as! [JFile]
                        if filez.count>0{
                           arrayOfPages = filez[myindex].thearray as! [[colorPath]]
                        }
```

So I assume I am subclassing UIBezierPath incorrectly because the only variable that work with Core Data is the one I made myself -- pathStrokeColor. Is my syntax wrong? Is it something to do with pathStrokeColor being an optional? Is it because I can't class my subclass to NSObject? How do I fix this?

Comment: You can't save any object into core-data.  It must be a number, date, string or data.  Generally if you want to store something other than that you convert it to data first to store it and decode it from data when you want to read it. Based on the code that you shared there does not appear to be anywhere that this is taking place.  Are you encoding and decoding it to data anywhere in your code?

Comment: Ah, sorry. JFile.thearray is of type transformable, so I cast colorPath to type NSObject when saving then convert back when loading. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: did you override `init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` and `encode(with aCoder: NSCoder)`?

Comment: nope. the entire colorPath class is just a subclass of uibezierpath and the variable pathstrokecolor, as presented above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't save any object into core-data.  It must be a number, date, string or data.  Generally if you want to store something other than that you convert it to data first to store it and decode it from data when you want to read it. Based on the code that you shared there does not appear to be anywhere that this is taking place.

When a property is transformable it allows you to store any object that conforms to `NSCoding` into core-data.  But this is not magic.  Objects that conform to `NSCoding` implement  `init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` and `encode(with aCoder: NSCoder)` which convert the object to and from data.

A `UIBezierPath` already conforms to `NSCoding`, so *technically* your subclass does as well.  But your subclass is not storing its extra property.  You have to also implement encoding in your subclass:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    if let color = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "pathStrokeColor") as? UIColor{
        pathStrokeColor = color
    }
}
override func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    super.encode(with: aCoder)
    if let color = pathStrokeColor{
        aCoder.encode(color, forKey: "pathStrokeColor")
    }
}
```